# How to autoselect a whole word when text view is tapped?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code wherein every character that is not a letter or digit is clickable individually... but, what I'm really trying to do is to select a word that is only between square braces [ ] in the text view. I know my code there is far from my desired output but I hope you guys can help me, thanks!

```
 public void clickedTextView (View v)
{
    labeltxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    text = labeltxt.getText().toString();
    labeltxt.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    spans = (Spannable) labeltxt.getText();
    iterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.US);
    iterator.setText(text);
    int start = iterator.first();
    for (int end = iterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator
            .next()) {
        String possibleWord = text.substring(start, end);


        if (!(Character.isLetterOrDigit(possibleWord.charAt(0)))) {
            clickSpan = getClickableSpan(possibleWord);
            spans.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AsteriskNinja yes